# Scraping with Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, screen-scraping

I have a strange problem-

Because of the strange way that this site presents time data, I wanted to write a small parser.

I was testing my code on one specific url -

[http://www.sfweekly.com/search/results/?keyword=*&type=events#type:events/page:57/](http://www.sfweekly.com/search/results/?keyword=%2a&type=events#type%3aevents/page:57/)

Note that when you visit the url, the page first loads a bunch of entries and then changes those entries. What's happening there is that it's going to the first page and then re-directing. How do I get around that?

To scrape I'm using

```
jsdom.env({
    html: url,
    scripts:['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'],
    done: function(errors,window){
                 //doSomething
```

I originally thought I could get around this with a pause, but that's not the case. Is there some way I can 'listen' for a redirect and wait until the real page has been loaded? I also have a feeling that the new entries may be entered with a jquery replace, but I'm not sure how to test that theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scraping ajax-y sites like this can be a real pain. In this case, it seems there is a way around it, because you can snoop around in the developer tools in your browser of choice and discover the ajax endpoint, and use that directly:

http://www.sfweekly.com/search/ajaxsearch/type%3aevents/page:57/

In some scenarios, javascript-y sites that intentionally try to foil scrapers, you have to use some kind of headless or automated browser situation. That's slow and annoying, avoid it if you can.

Comment: avoiding an automated browser situation is kind of the whole point of using node.js for scraping.

Comment: Look at [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). Note that zombie.js works in node 0.8 but is broken in 0.10. Also if you fetch the page using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and parse the response with [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), you might be able write some logic to figure out where the redirect is pointing to and request that page directly

Comment: @pguardiario i'd love to see a node scraper that is lighter weight than a headless browser and safely evals JS in whatever it scrapes off the web. do you know of such a thing? (maybe zombie.js, as Noah suggests, is the thing? looks interesting).

Comment: No, I don't know of anything but I'm interested, that's why I followed this question.

Comment: ohh that's cool. Thanks for that - how did you find the ajax endpoint? I tried looking at network in my chrome console but there was a lot to look at.

Comment: @praks5432 You're barking up the right tree. The network tab in the chrome devtools is useful, the timeline can be useful too. I just scanned for requests that weren't ads (ads will often be served from a different domain), images, scripts, or css. It can be helpful to sort the network tab by type. Here the path is pretty obviously named /search/ajaxsearch so it jumped out.